# C# Trimming on both sides of the string all required characters and character sets in order

Tags: c#, string, trim

My input consists of a string of indeterminate length and content. I need to trim all spaces, characters `#` `\t` and fragments `//` `/*` `*/` at its beginning and end. All these symbols and character sets follow one another. If there was something else between them, you need to stop.

Example:

`"///g, hhh/ , test" ===> "/g, hhh/ , test"`

`"//*g, hhh/ , test " ===> "*g, hhh/ , test"`

`"#/test" ===> "/test"`

`"hello  //" ===> "hello"`

**Important clarification:** I need to know how many characters I trimmed at the beginning and how many characters I trimmed at the end.

Also, I wouldn't want to use regular expressions because this code is very performance sensitive. As far as I know, regular expressions are pretty slow. However, if my task cannot be done with loops, or the like is extremely difficult - I am ready to use regular expressions.

So far I have tried code like this. The task is complicated by the fact that some symbols represent two characters following each other.

```cs
private const char specialSymbol_1 = '/';
private const char specialSymbol_2 = '*';
private const char specialSymbol_3 = '#';

private void ObserveTrim(ref string target, ref int start, ref int end) {
    int s = 0; int e = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; ++i) {
        char c = target[i];
        
        bool flag = false;
        if (target.Length > 1) {
            if (i == 0) {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_2 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1;
            }
            else if (i == target.Length - 1) {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_2 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1;
            }
            else {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_2;
            }
        }
        
        if (flag) continue;
        
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && c != specialSymbol_3) {
            s = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = target.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        char c = target[i];
        
        bool flag = false;
        if (target.Length > 1) {
            if (i == 0) {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_2 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1;
            }
            else if (i == target.Length - 1) {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_2 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1;
            }
            else {
                flag = c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_1 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i + 1] == specialSymbol_2 ||
                    c == specialSymbol_1 && target[i - 1] == specialSymbol_2;
            }
        }
        
        if (flag) continue;
        
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && c != specialSymbol_3) {
            e = target.Length - 1 - i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    start += s;
    end -= e;
    target = target.Substring(s, target.Length - s - e);
}
```

But this code doesn't work as expected.
**Example:**
`"///g, hhh/ , test" ===> "g, hhh/ , test"`
`"/*g, hhh/ , test" ===> "*g, hhh/ , test"`

These are just a few examples of his incorrect work, in fact there are several dozen of them.

It simply does not take into account some characters or their sequence. I am not strong in such algorithms, and any help is welcome.

Comment: If "this code doesn't work as expected", you can state what your expectations were and what your code did instead (which is *what* your code is doing wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While having all strings to `trim`, I suggest check all of them with `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`. With a help of `ReadOnlySpan<char>` we can do it without creating many unwanted substrings.

Since you want to get `3` parameters - `result` (trimmed string), how many symbols were removed from the `left` and from the `right`, let's combine them in a tuple:

**Code:**

```
  public static (string result, int left, int right) MyTrim(
    string value, params string[] trim) {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || trim is null || trim.Length == 0)
      return (value, 0, 0);

    int trimmedLeft = 0;
    int trimmedRight = 0;  
      
    var span = value.AsSpan();

    for (bool keep = true; keep; ) {
      keep = false;

      foreach (var item in trim)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && span.StartsWith(item)) {
          trimmedLeft += item.Length;   
          span = span.Slice(item.Length);
          keep = true;

          break;
        }
    }

    for (bool keep = true; keep; ) {
      keep = false;

      foreach (var item in trim)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && span.EndsWith(item)) {
          trimmedRight += item.Length;   
          span = span.Slice(0, span.Length - item.Length);
          keep = true;

          break;
        }
    }

    return (span.ToString(), trimmedLeft, trimmedRight);
  }
```

**Usage:**

```
string value = "///g, hhh/ , test";

(string result, int left, int right) = MyTrim(
  value, " ", "#", "\t", "//", "/*", "*/");
```

**Demo:**

```
using System.Linq;

...

string[] tests = new string[] {
  "///g, hhh/ , test",
  "//*g, hhh/ , test ", 
  "#/test",
  "hello  //",
};
      
var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => (test, result : MyTrim(test, " ", "#", "\t", "//", "/*", "*/")))                       
  .Select(pair => $"{pair.test,30} ===> {pair.result.result} (left: {pair.result.left}; right: {pair.result.right}) "));  
                
Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Output:**

```
             ///g, hhh/ , test ===> /g, hhh/ , test (left: 2; right: 0) 
            //*g, hhh/ , test  ===> *g, hhh/ , test (left: 2; right: 1) 
                        #/test ===> /test (left: 1; right: 0) 
                     hello  // ===> hello (left: 0; right: 4)
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJG9bi)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I am forced to use a special version of C# (I have no idea which one, as I only have access to write a script that is compiled by a third party program and then used in it) I cannot compile using tuples, and some classes like Tuple. However, at the moment I am modifying this code to suit my needs, and in the end I will let you know what will come of it.

Comment: I don't have the option to use Span. Are there any equivalents for earlier versions of C#? I assume that I have 3-4 version (with some restrictions). I also can't install NuGet packages

Comment: @Unable error: you can use `value.Substring(...)` instead of `span.Slice(...)`, but it will slow down the routine.

Comment: @Unable error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LJG9bi, `MyTrimOld` method: no `Tuple`s, no `Span`s

Comment: This answer is essentially the solution. For those who run into the same restrictions as me, I posted my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76212877/16029325

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that Dmitry's answer was exhaustive, I could not apply it in its original form, because very limited by the compiler.

I was writing a script for a program and I don't even know what language version it supports. In this regard, I rewrote the code and used only those constructs that I managed to compile. I publish this downgrade for those who find themselves in my conditions. It's a pity that we had to sacrifice convenience and performance.
However, I'll mark his answer as the solution, as most compilers will handle this code in modern times.

I also partially edited the question to make the problem and its solution look more descriptive for those who come across a similar one.

```cs
private const char specialSymbol_1 = '/';
private const char specialSymbol_2 = '*';
private const char specialSymbol_3 = '#';

private void CheckContent() {
    int leftWordStart = ...;
    int leftWordEnd = ...;
    string leftWord = ...;
    MyTrim(ref leftWord, ref leftWordStart, ref leftWordEnd,
        new string[6] { " ", "\t", new string(specialSymbol_1, 2), new string(new char[2] {specialSymbol_1, specialSymbol_2}), 
            new string(new char[2] {specialSymbol_2, specialSymbol_1}), specialSymbol_3.ToString()});
    //...
}

private void MyTrim(ref string target, ref int start, ref int end, string[] trim) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(target) || trim == null || trim.Length == 0) return;

    int trimmedLeft = 0;
    int trimmedRight = 0;

    bool keep = true;
    while (keep) {
        keep = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < trim.Length; ++i) {
            string item = trim[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && target.StartsWith(item)) {
                trimmedLeft += item.Length;   
                target = target.Substring(item.Length);
                keep = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    keep = true;
    while (keep) {
        keep = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < trim.Length; ++i) {
            string item = trim[i];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && target.EndsWith(item)) {
                trimmedRight += item.Length;
                target = target.Substring(0, target.Length - item.Length);
                keep = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    start += trimmedLeft;
    end -= trimmedRight;
}
```